# Passing am XML file to a web service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, url, soap

I have been working on a JAX-WS Server. I have the server and client both running and have done a few string tests to make sure I set them up correctly. I would like to start working towards passing an .XML file over to another Web service by a URL. I want to pull the XML file from my directory and get a response from the other server if it is authenticated. I'm new to the whole soap concept and am trying to wrap my head around it. Could i do an HTTP/URL call through JAX-WS or am I completly off track?

```
[WebMethod]

public void ProcessXMLFile(XmlDocument doc)
{

      /// process doc as a local variable
}

Then in the call to do the following

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\Users\Me\xmlfile.xml");
/// Call to web service:
publicwebservice.ProcessXMLFile(doc);
```

This is how I was thinking about it in a pseudo code type way. If any one knows of any further tutorials out there to help me pass an XML file to a web-service and receive a response?

Comment: You want a soap client.  Here's the Java example: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html

Comment: @djb That is the same as a JAX-WS correct? I'm already at the process of doing soap calls from the JAX client to the server and vise versa.

Comment: ok, what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @djb Im curious if it is possible for me to pass an .XML file to another server. Or if I'm off track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to send XML over SOAP
you generally have two options...

Either Base64 the String and un-Base64 it on the other side...
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("Test".getBytes());
System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));

byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes);
System.out.println("decodedBytes " + new String(decodedBytes));
```

Or escape the XML you want to send.  This turns < into `&lt;` and > into `&gt`;
StringEscapeUtils  (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has a method to escape XML

Generally go with the second option if you want to keep it human readable.

Comment: So a JAX-WS is not what I'm looking for right? Since it does a soap call between a client and server and not a server between a server? Where you you think I should start or what I should use to start this? Also where can i find examples on "sending a xml file to a url server?". Thanks you alot.

Comment: You do want JAXWS in order to make the server and client code.  Your XML field is just a string.  Typically you start by making an XSD and WSDL.  Then you use JAXWS to auto-generate the server and client from those 2 files.  In your situation, it looks like you have a client, a middle-man service, and a final service.  So your middle-man service is both a server and a client.  When it gets a message (as a server), it calls another server (as a client).  You don't really send files over SOAP - you might send the contents of a file, in which case you must decide between the 2 methods I mentioned